# Login to Hamachi using IPv6 times out

Tags: networking, vpn, ipv6

My cable modem uses IPv6 and so does my LAN. I want to connect my laptop to the [hamachi](http://vpn.net/) service. However, the laptop tries to connect via IPv4 and this attempt fails.

The network configuration of my laptop looks like this

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1e:64:47:00:cc  
          inet addr:192.168.0.13  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::21e:64ff:fe47:cc/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2a02:908:f621:8500:21e:64ff:fe47:cc/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2a02:908:f621:8500:5c4e:d721:be73:ffb3/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:616810 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:291628 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:919920604 (919.9 MB)  TX bytes:32471751 (32.4 MB)

ham0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 7a:79:19:5b:cc:3c  
          inet addr:25.91.204.60  Bcast:25.255.255.255  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: 2620:9b::195b:cc3c/96 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::7879:19ff:fe5b:cc3c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1404  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:113 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:22370 (22.3 KB)
```

and according to the config file IPv6 is enabled

```
$ cat /var/lib/logmein-hamachi/h2-engine.ini
Bits                 20129066
Bits2                0001008c
Conn.Last            0
CreateAcc            0
DegradeKey           
HostSent             
IPv6Cfg              2
LicExpiry            1387220302
LicType              0
LmiEmail             **************
NetState             183-243-613, 1, 1
NetState             185-627-460, 1, 1
Nickname             **************
Reconnect            1
RetryDisc            8
VIP4Addr             25.91.204.60
VIP4Mask             255.0.0.0
```

However, the service is resolved to a IPv4 address and connection to this address takes very long and then fails (probably because IPv4 is used):

```
01.11 12:21:39.157 sys: go_online, reconnect 1
01.11 12:21:39.157 ses: selected (h-app03-03.hamachi.cc, 5805)
01.11 12:21:39.157 ses: selected 01 connection type
01.11 12:21:39.269 ses: resolving h-app03-03.hamachi.cc ..
01.11 12:21:39.482 ses: connecting to 212.118.234.69:12975 ..
01.11 12:23:46.671 ses: connection is established
01.11 12:23:46.783 ses: control connection is bound to 192.168.0.13
01.11 12:23:46.783 ses: << msg_helo ..
01.11 12:23:46.872 ses: io error, send, 110
01.11 12:23:46.873 ses: error 3, retryable yes
01.11 12:23:46.873 ses: go_offline, keep_tunnels 1, login_on_relaunch 0, actual state 10 ..
01.11 12:23:47.193 ses: reconnect delay: 389 sec
```

I already tried `sudo hamachi set-ip-mode ipv6` but this does not change the fact that IPv4 is used.

Is there any way to make Hamachi work over IPv6? Any help would be appreciated!

PS: I use the latest version of hamachi: 2.1.0.119

Comment: What about hardcoding the resolution of Hamachi hosts (e.g. `h-app03-03.hamachi.cc`) in `/etc/hosts` to IPv6 addresses?. Just guessing...